# how to get ManyToMany field data in model save method

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

```
class Product(models.Model):
    varient_property = models.ManyToManyField(to='store.AttributeValue', blank=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # here varient_propery is manytomany field
        # here i am saving this from django admin panel
        print(self.varient_property.all())
```

many to many class

```
class AttributeValue(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

the print statement returns none

how can I get many to many data after my model gets save?

I want all set many-to-many relations.

thanks in advance.

Comment: The m2m data are added by using some dedicated methods, `add()` and `set()` not at the time of `AttributeValue` instance creation

Comment: thank you @JPG. how can i get data in model's save method?

Comment: @CosmicReindeer I am getting previously saved data. not updated the updated one

Comment: The m2m data will not be present in the save method *"at the time of `AttributeValue` instance creation"*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

If you want all the records from `AttributeValue` model you need to use the `all()` method on the class not on the instance that you obtain from `varient_property` in `Product` model.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    varient_property = models.ManyToManyField(to='store.AttributeValue', blank=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
         print(AttributeValue.objects.all()) #like this
```

Comment: I tried it. but it returns old values, not the updated ones. and thanks for the help. I found the answer. I need to get many-to-many field values from admin.py where we define classes.